# Laravel Saving certain files as a bin file

Tags: laravel

When 3d model files are uploaded to my site for some reason the extension is changed to .bin, This is causing issues with a javascript plugin that is used to display the file.

How can i prevent this from happening? I want the .glb or .gltf ext to remain the same.

Currently files that are uploaded the information is saved in the database with original name, extension, file path with link like 5454thghg.bin, and other info such as size.

Theres code included in the script so that when i go to download a file it gives me the file with the original name and extension that was uploaded so i know its possible to get the link

Here is the code.

```
public function upload(Request $request){
        $type = array(
            "jpg"=>"image",
            "jpeg"=>"image",
            "png"=>"image",
            "svg"=>"image",
            "webp"=>"image",
            "gif"=>"image",
            "mp4"=>"video",
            "mpg"=>"video",
            "mpeg"=>"video",
            "webm"=>"video",
            "ogg"=>"video",
            "avi"=>"video",
            "mov"=>"video",
            "flv"=>"video",
            "swf"=>"video",
            "mkv"=>"video",
            "wmv"=>"video",
            "wma"=>"audio",
            "aac"=>"audio",
            "wav"=>"audio",
            "mp3"=>"audio",
            "zip"=>"archive",
            "rar"=>"archive",
            "7z"=>"archive",
            "doc"=>"document",
            "txt"=>"document",
            "docx"=>"document",
            "pdf"=>"document",
            "csv"=>"document",
            "xml"=>"document",
            "ods"=>"document",
            "xlr"=>"document",
            "xls"=>"document",
            "xlsx"=>"document",
            "glb" => "cad",
            "gltf" => "cad",
            "usdz" => "cad",
            "3dm" => "Rhino",
            "stl" => "Stereolithography"
        );

        if($request->hasFile('aiz_file')){
            $upload = new Upload;
            $extension = strtolower($request->file('aiz_file')->getClientOriginalExtension());

            if(isset($type[$extension])){
                $upload->file_original_name = null;
                $arr = explode('.', $request->file('aiz_file')->getClientOriginalName());
                for($i=0; $i < count($arr)-1; $i++){
                    if($i == 0){
                        $upload->file_original_name .= $arr[$i];
                    }
                    else{
                        $upload->file_original_name .= ".".$arr[$i];
                    }
                }

                $path = $request->file('aiz_file')->store('uploads/all', 'local');
                $size = $request->file('aiz_file')->getSize();

                // Return MIME type ala mimetype extension
                $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

                // Get the MIME type of the file
                $file_mime = finfo_file($finfo, base_path('public/').$path);

                if($type[$extension] == 'image' && get_setting('disable_image_optimization') != 1){
                    try {
                        $img = Image::make($request->file('aiz_file')->getRealPath())->encode();
                        $height = $img->height();
                        $width = $img->width();
                        if($width > $height && $width > 1500){
                            $img->resize(1500, null, function ($constraint) {
                                $constraint->aspectRatio();
                            });
                        }elseif ($height > 1500) {
                            $img->resize(null, 800, function ($constraint) {
                                $constraint->aspectRatio();
                            });
                        }
                        $img->save(base_path('public/').$path);
                        clearstatcache();
                        $size = $img->filesize();

                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        //dd($e);
                    }
                }

                if (env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER') == 's3') {
                    Storage::disk('s3')->put(
                        $path,
                        file_get_contents(base_path('public/').$path),
                        [
                            'visibility' => 'public',
                            'ContentType' =>  $extension == 'svg' ? 'image/svg+xml' : $file_mime
                        ]
                    );
                    if($arr[0] != 'updates') {
                        unlink(base_path('public/').$path);
                    }
                }

                $upload->extension = $extension;
                $upload->file_name = $path;
                $upload->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $upload->type = $type[$upload->extension];
                $upload->file_size = $size;
                $upload->save();
            }
            return '{}';
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please edit your question and add the relevant parts of your code *here*, not off-site.

Comment: AFAICT there are potentially 3 files saved by this code - the original, a resized version, and a copy on an s3 bucket? So which one has the `.bin` extension?  Can you give us an example filename that causes the problem?  For that file, what is the filename that is saved in `uploads/all/`?  Does the resizing happen for that file, and if yes, what is the resized filename?  And what is the s3 filename?

Comment: Well files are saved localy unless specified to save to s3. This is the link to a file https://jewelrycadmarket.com/public/uploads/all/QuQKiswVy1SngLV7SbF1ejDdtIQeysJV9qGDiGjm.bin , its basically a glb that is renamed to .bin by the code. It works with modelviewer 3d viewer but not babylon. For non 3d model files ssuch as zip, pdf, png it saved with randomize name.ext such as https://jewelrycadmarket.com/public/uploads/all/C61HFwFQvnTMzdBX0bHWgkHwvwisGtziMu165KjD.png

Comment: So to confirm - the s3 code is not relevant here (you could remove it if it is not relevant to this problem)? "*its basically a glb*" - OK so you uploaded `something.glb`, and it wound up as `<hash>.bin`? "*It works with modelviewer 3d viewer but not babylon*" - I don't know what this means. So to ask again - is the resize code running, is the `.bin` file the resized version?  Or both the original and the resized version end up as `.bin`?

Comment: correct s3 code not relevant. No resizing happens. i could saved the .bin from the server and rename to .glb and view it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From discussion in the comments, it turns out that neither the s3 code nor the image resizing code is relevant to this problem.  So the code exhibiting the problem can be boiled down to:

```
public function upload(Request $request){
    $type = array(
        // ... list of extensions ...
        "glb" => "cad",
    );

    $extension = strtolower($request->file('aiz_file')->getClientOriginalExtension());

    if ($request->hasFile('aiz_file')) {
        if (isset($type[$extension])) {

            // This line saves the uploaded file, and somehow changes extension
            $path = $request->file('aiz_file')->store('uploads/all', 'local');

        }
    }
}
```

If that line is really causing the problem, it is not your own code, it is Laravel itself getting something wrong.  Checking [the docs for file uploads](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-uploads), it says:

> The file's extension will be determined by examining the file's MIME type

OK, so the MIME type is somehow confusing Laravel.  It seems like there is probably nothing we can do about that.  So what other options are there?

Checking the docs again, immediately following that section is [a section on specifying your own file name](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#specifying-a-file-name).  You can do that with the `storeAs()` method, which takes a filename as the 2nd parameter:

```
$path = $request->file('aiz_file')->storeAs(
    'uploads/all', $request->file('aiz_file')->getClientOriginalName()
);
```

If you want to keep the default Laravel behaviour of using a random hash as a filename, you can check the Laravel source on how they do that.  We can see [`store()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.php#L34) uses [`hashName()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/039cde6b25204dea88f3904947b7f78613b1cb0d/src/Illuminate/Http/FileHelpers.php#L42) to generate the filename, and that it does that like so (simplified):

```
$hash = Illuminate\Support\Str::random(40);
```

So you could use something like:

```
$hash = Illuminate\Support\Str::random(40);
$extension = $request->file('aiz_file')->getClientOriginalExtension();

$path = $request->file('aiz_file')->storeAs(
    'uploads/all', $hash . '.' . $extension
);
```

Comment: This works now it saves as orignialfilename.glb(original extension). Look https://imgur.com/YpvW4av how do i keep the randomize filename but keep original extension?

Comment: @user2002220 Updated again.

Comment: i got a error on upload. `[2022-02-10 07:38:12] production.ERROR: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Str' not found {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Class 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\Str' not found at /var/www/vhosts/districtties.com/httpdocs/app/Http/Controllers/AizUploadController.php:125)
[stacktrace]`

Comment: You need to import the class: `use Illuminate\Support\Str;` at the top of your file, like in the top of [the file with `hashName()` I linked to](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/039cde6b25204dea88f3904947b7f78613b1cb0d/src/Illuminate/Http/FileHelpers.php#L42) ...

Comment: Works perfect now thanks!